# corosync and pacemaker HA failing to identify mysql

Tags: mysql, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I have a Basic Corosync Setup with two Node cluster , I have enabled Floating IP and tested and is working perfectly fine
I wanted to add a MYSQL 8.0 Resource as I want the floating IP to move to Active Node if MySQL is crashed or stopped

The Resource I added was
crm configure 
primitive p_mysql ocf:heartbeat:mysql 
op monitor depth="0" timeout="30s" interval="20s"

It reports Mysql Failed on both Nodes , whereas they are working and my apps can connect to them

CRM status shows Below

Failed Actions:

- p_mysql_start_0 on NODE01 'unknown error' (1): call=93, status=complete, exitreason='MySQL server failed to start (pid=18004) (rc=0), please check your installation',
  last-rc-change='Thu Aug 24 14:09:52 2023', queued=0ms, exec=2093ms
- p_mysql_start_0 on NODE02 'unknown error' (1): call=68, status=complete, exitreason='MySQL server failed to start (pid=20367) (rc=0), please check your installation',
  last-rc-change='Thu Aug 24 14:09:54 2023', queued=0ms, exec=2093ms

Any Suggestion would be helpful

There is no such logs in corosync

Tried Multiple Configurations with CRM with no Success